# jQuery UI Dialog Code Help

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

Okay, don't laugh, but my friend gave me a fix to a jQuery UI code before I asked for another fix here, and now I have no idea how to combine the two.  I'm a total n00b so please help me out here.  I tried, but keep getting a syntax error?

I need to merge this (I think it goes right after title):

```
beforeClose: function(){   $(this).remove();   }
```

Into this:

```
function openDialog(url) {
    $("<div class='popupDialog'>Loading...</div>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: '900',
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            title: 'Bonus Features'
        }).bind('dialogclose', function() {
            jdialog.dialog('destroy');
        }).load(url, function() {
            $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] ).bind('dialogopen', function() {
                    adjustJQueryDialogOverlay();
                });
                $(this).dialog("open");
        });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center']);
});
```

Can anyone please help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function openDialog(url) {
    $("<div class='popupDialog'>Loading...</div>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: '900',
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            title: 'Bonus Features', //don't forget the comma
            beforeClose: function(){   $(this).remove();   } //placed here
        }).bind('dialogclose', function() {
            jdialog.dialog('destroy');
        }).load(url, function() {
            $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] ).bind('dialogopen', function() {
                    adjustJQueryDialogOverlay();
                });
                $(this).dialog("open");
        });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center']);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  Hey, can you perhaps suggest a good website that might teach me how to write code without syntax errors?

Comment: This is a good place to start for jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery On a side note, you don't need a comma for the last property (which is why `title` didn't have a comma before). If you're using something from jQueryUI and are not sure why it's not working, take a look at the code in the demos on their site: http://jqueryui.com/demos/ Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much.  That'll definitely help a lot.  But I have another question for you.  The fix my friend added recently is for the background overlay.  I had an issue where if the dialog height extended beyond the original website background, it would cut off the overlay right in the middle.  His fix solved it.  Continued...

Comment: But now I have a minor but annoying problem.  Every time I open a very long pop-up, then a short one, the stretched scroll bars from the longer remains.  Like when I open the short afterwards, I can scroll down way beyond the background like with the longer, but I can only see the overlay.  I don’t think the settings are unloading properly once the dialog is closed.  Would you have a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't messed around with jQueryUI in some time. Off the top of my head, I'd suggest you add another property for `autoResize:true,`. Place this after `title` (including the comma ;) ). However, I'm not sure if autoResize is supported anymore. If that doesn't work, you could start a new question as someone else with more experience in jQueryUI might know :)

Comment: Unfortunately... but thank you very much for your help.  You're very good. (:

Comment: Oh, I'm doing a website to promote my upcoming book.  It's launching soon. (:

Comment: Hey keyboard, someone has a fix for me, but I don't know how to embed it yet.  Can you please help me?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011939/jquery-ui-dialog-scroll-bar-overlay-settings-wont-unload

Comment: Sadly, no, but my friend came up with a solution.  I'll post it soon.